# Select niece and change siblings

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dropdown, picker

I have this bootstrap (minimized) code.

```
<div id='DD_type' class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn" ></button>
   <span id='af'>Type</span>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li> 
         I want this HTML(its more than text) in my button
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div id='Another Dropdown' class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn" ></button>
   <span id='af'>Type</span>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li> 
         I want this HTML(its more than text) in my button
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I want to fill the button with the first element in the li.
What I now have is a static soluction.

```
$(function() {
   $('#DD_LayOut>button').html($('#DD_LayOut>ul>li').html())
}
```

However I would like to have a generic solution. (Yes I did some searching).

Mine is not working at all.

```
 $('.dropdown > button').html($(This).siblings('ul>li:first').html())
```

Could someone help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you can provide the `html()` method with a function as the scope of that function will be the `button` element which you can use to traverse the DOM to find the required `li`, something like this:

```
$('.dropdown > button').html(function(i, h) {
    return $(this).siblings('.dropdown-menu').find('li:first').html();
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/3ktetn4x/)

Comment: Thank you so much, The find li:first combination is what I was looking for!